# Cannot call value of non-function type 'Any'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to fix this problem `Cannot call value of non-function type 'Any'`
this is my code

```
            databaseRef.child("ServiceA").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
                DataSnapshot in
                let title = DataSnapshot.value!("title") as! String
                self.posts.insert(PostStruct.init(title: title), at: 0)
            })
```

[image]

Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSnapshot.value is `Any` and according to the documentation you could cast it in different types.

> Data types returned: + NSDictionary + NSArray + NSNumber (also includes booleans) + NSString

If I understood your snipped well, in you case, you need to cast "DataSnapshot" into a dictionary in order to access with a subscript.
You can try this:

```swift
databaseRef.child("ServiceA").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
                DataSnapshot in
    let title = (snapshot.value as? [String: Any])?["title"] as? String
    self.posts.insert(PostStruct.init(title: title), at: 0)
})
```

Please also note that, in order to prevent crashes, I removed the force-wrap so "title" would be an optional String.